# Binding web-audio node to dom element in class prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-audio-api

My goal is this: to create a class, "BoundSound", which will reference a Web Audio [AudioNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) and have a method to dynamically bind dom elements to different properties of that AudioNode. So that, for example, I could create a BoundSound object, referencing an oscillator, and bind the oscillator's type property to a selector element, so that, when the selected option changes from "sine" to "square", the type of the oscillator would also change. And then use the same method to bind a numeric input field to the oscillator's gain property so that someone could type in a number and that would change the oscillator's gain to that value.

I've been trying different methods of assigning event handlers to no success. Here's what I have so far:

```
function BoundSound(audioNode) {
  this.audioNode = audioNode;
  this.bindings = {};
};

BoundSound.prototype.bind = function(property, element) {
  element[0].value = this.audioNode[property];
  this.bindings[property] = element[0];
  $('document').on("change", '#'+element[0].id, 
                    this.change(property, element[0].value));
}

BoundSound.prototype.change = function(prop, value) {
  this.audioNode[prop] = value;
  this.bindings[prop].value = value;
}

var bs = new BoundSound(createOsc());
bs.bind('type', $('#typeSelect'));
```

The "change" method gets called once when the "bind" method is called, but then doesn't get called again when the selector element's value changes.

Am I on the right track with trying to create event-listeners this way, or is there a better solution to binding a dom element to a web-audio node? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the `onchange` event be on  `$('#typeSelect')` element instead of `$('document')`?

Comment: changing the last line of bind() to `element.on("change", this.change(property, element[0].value));` gives the same results. Fires once when bind() is called and then not again. I'd tried the $('document').on() method, passing in the element's id as a parameter thinking it'd make a difference, but no dice.